# Ubuntu not booting from USB on laptop (no optical drive)

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I'm using a Kingston 16GB USB, with the Unetbootin program. (I've tried both downloading the installation iso manually and adding it, or using the program to download.) I've tried creating the bootable USB on an iMac, the laptop and also a desktop.

I've booted into the setup of the laptop and changed the boot order to make sure it boots from that drive first. (There is no optical drive so that isn't a problem.) It's an Acer Aspire AS3810TZ.

Upon booting it gives this message:

```
SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

I get this no matter how I create the USB, it just sits there. I left the laptop for an hour and it hadn't moved.

I've also tried on a different 4GB USB (Generic) and that did the same.

Comment: If you have access to a Windows box, try using [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). I've always had more success with that than with Unetbootin.

Comment: Ok! Great. I'll add my comment as an answer for you to accept it and prevent this question from showing up in the *Unanswered* section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a Windows box, try using [LiLi](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/). I've always had more success with that than with Unetbootin.

[image: LiLi]

Comment: Thumbs up! I eventually managed to get a working USB bootable partition with Ubuntu 16.04 installation image by following your advice, after two days of unsuccessful attempts with Ubuntu-based toolkits.